# Does org-babel for groovy take arguments?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, literate-programming

I am trying to pass an argument to a groovy babel block but I'm not sure it accepts arguments?  The [documentation](http://orgmode.org/org.html#var) says that it is language-specific but I didn't find any documentation for [ob-groovy](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/plain/lisp/ob-groovy.el).

For example, I want to try to feed one section of my document into the groovy block:

```
#+NAME:current_paths

path1
path2
path3


** Groovy Processing
#+BEGIN_SRC groovy :var paths=current_paths :results output :cache yes
    paths.each {
      println "PATH: $it"
    }
#+END_SRC
```

But I get:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: 
No such property: paths     for class: groovy-6160mqV
    at groovy-6160mqV.run(groovy-6160mqV:2)
```

Does anyone know if groovy babel support includes arguments?  Or maybe I'm doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code you linked, it seems that no, there is no support for the `:vars` parameter.

The `:results` and `:cache` parameters should be handled directly by `org-babel` so these should work.

---

If you're interested in the details, the function used to expand the source code body (mainly in charge of adding code before and after, and initializing variables) is the generic function `org-babel-expand-body:generic` (not a groovy-specific function), and the third (optional) parameter of this function (lines to add to define variables) is not specified.

Comment: I see. . thanks for the extra info explaining where the arguments support comes from.