# With org-babel how can I read a result block and pass arguments?

Tags: org-babel

I asked a [similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12750/does-org-babel-for-groovy-take-arguments) a few years ago but I never did figure out how to proceed. I ended up aborting my excursion into org-babel.  However, I can see how this would be really valuable, to intermix a basic `org` file with scripts and results.  Unfortunately, it seems either groovy support in org-babel doesn't have all the bells or whistles or I just don't know the workarounds.  I think it's an element of both.

I want to do something like this:

```
#+NAME: do_something
#+BEGIN_SRC groovy  :results output
  // do something groovy to generate results
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: process_something
#+BEGIN_SRC groovy :results output :vars mylist=do_something
  // now process all those groovy things
  mylist.each{ thing ->
      println thing
  }
#+END_SRC
```

However, it seems groovy doesn't have `vars` (see original question, above).

I also tried this:

```
#+NAME: process_something(mylist=do_something)
#+BEGIN_SRC groovy :results output
  mylist.each{ thing ->
      println thing
  }
#+END_SRC
```

Which also doesn't work.  Additionally, ideally I would like to reuse a code block which again means somehow getting an argument into the code block.

So what it comes down to is:

1. How can I process a result block with groovy?
2. How can I pass an argument into a groovy block?

Comment: I think it is a good idea to ask org-mode developers for help. `ob-groovy.el` simply doesn't support `:var` right now. Someone needs to add the support.